# Taking a picture then check its orientation, then rotate it then save it

Tags: android, optimization, orientation, photo

I've tried to create an application (with Unity3D) that uses an Intent to take a photo and save it.

My issue is that saving the picture then checking its orientation to rotate it if needed and then saving again, is really long.

I think that's due to the fact that I'm using too much tools.

Do you have some tips to reduce the process time?

Here's my (edited) code, thanks in advance :

```
package com.falsename.my;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhotoPlugin implements myAndroidPlugin 
{
    private boolean canTakePhotos;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private static PhotoPlugin instance;
    private myActivity activity;
    private File photoFile;

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException 
    {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = this.activity.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(myActivity a) 
    {
        if(canTakePhotos)
        {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(a.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("my", ex.toString());
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                             ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    a.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void TakePicture()
    {
        instance.dispatchTakePictureIntent(instance.activity);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Context c, myActivity a) 
    {
        instance = this;
        this.activity = a;
        canTakePhotos = a.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);        
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResume(myActivity a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPause(myActivity a) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityNewIntent(myActivity a, Intent intent) 
    {

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(myActivity a,
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {    
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            {
                a.SendMessage("PhotoListener", "OnPhotoTaken", "");

                PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams params = new PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams();
                params.activity = a;
                params.path = this.mCurrentPhotoPath;
                params.file = this.photoFile;

                new PhotoPluginOrientationChecker().execute(params);
            }
    }    
}
```

and :

```
package com.falsename.my;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhotoPluginOrientationChecker extends AsyncTask<PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams, Void, Void>
{    
    myActivity a;
    String path; 
    File file;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams ... params) {

        a = params[0].activity;
        path = params[0].path;
        file = params[0].file;

        try 
        {
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch(orientation) 
            {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    SaveBitmap(RotateBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(a, Uri.fromFile(file)), 90));
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    SaveBitmap(RotateBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(a, Uri.fromFile(file)), 180));
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    SaveBitmap(RotateBitmap(getBitmapFromUri(a, Uri.fromFile(file)), 270));
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("my", "Photo error");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        a.SendMessage("PhotoListener", "OnPhotoSaved", path);    
    }


    private void SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try
            {
                if (out != null) 
                {
                    out.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
          matrix.postRotate(angle);
          return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(myActivity a, Uri imageUri) 
    {
        ContentResolver cr = a.getContentResolver();
        cr.notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with :

```
package com.falsename.my;

import java.io.File;

public class PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams 
{
    public myActivity activity;
    public String path;
    public File file;
}
```

Comment: Checking EXIF data is really long and should be done in background as well as all operations with bitmaps.

Comment: Even in a thread, I'm afraid that's too long.. (> 20s sometimes)
I tried MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION but it changes nothing :/

Comment: But still it should be done in background, because if not it'll cause ANRs.

Comment: And also - why do you need to check the 180 issue? Maybe, it'll be enough for you to check that height>width (for portrait)? Then you'll not need to go with EXIF

Comment: Nope, if the rotation is 270, this doesn't work.

Comment: I've just used the background. This works well, but it doesn't change the fact that the modification is made too long after.

In fact, I don't know if the 270° is possible, I've read that changes according to the device/application.

Comment: I've just tested. Using bmp.getWidth() > bmp.getHeight() and using ExifInterface is the same. I think that saving/rotating is the operation that takes a lot of time. Maybe my picture is just too detailled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found :

1. Use background to operate images
2. Take the image, scale it down (I've done a .1f ratio), do the operations, it's quite fast, use the result.
3. Do the operations on the final image, once it's finished, use it.

If the final image is long to compute, the scaled one is not, but shows the user that the picture has been taken.

Here's the checker code (not cleaned but will do for now) :

```
package com.falsename.my;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
//import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhotoPluginOrientationChecker extends AsyncTask<PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams, Void, Void>
{    
    PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams params;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams ... params) {

        this.params = params[0];

        Log.v("my", "final mode");

        if(this.params.highBitmap == null)
        {
            this.params.highBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(this.params.activity, Uri.fromFile(this.params.file));        
            this.params.angle = (this.params.highBitmap.getWidth() > this.params.highBitmap.getHeight()) ? 90 : 0;        
        }

        Bitmap bmp = this.params.highBitmap;
        String path = this.params.path;

        if(this.params.low)
        {
            path += "_thumb.jpg";
            bmp = HighToLowBitmap(bmp);
        }

        if(this.params.angle != 0)
        {
            Log.v("my", "rotate");
            SaveBitmap(RotateBitmap(bmp, this.params.angle), path);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Bitmap HighToLowBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth() / 10, bmp.getHeight() / 10, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        Log.v("my", "OnPostExecute");        

        if(this.params.low)
        {
            this.params.low = false;
            this.params.activity.SendMessage("PhotoListener", "OnThumbnailSaved", this.params.path + "_thumb.jpg");                
            new PhotoPluginOrientationChecker().execute(params);
        }
        else
        {
            this.params.activity.SendMessage("PhotoListener", "OnPhotoSaved", this.params.path);
        }
    }


    private static void SaveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String path)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try
            {
                if (out != null) 
                {
                    out.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
          matrix.postRotate(angle);
          return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(myActivity a, Uri imageUri) 
    {
        ContentResolver cr = a.getContentResolver();
        cr.notifyChange(imageUri, null);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with :

```
package com.falsename.my;

import java.io.File;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class PhotoPluginOrientationCheckerParams 
{
    public myActivity activity;
    public String path;
    public File file;
    public boolean low = true;
    public Bitmap highBitmap;
    public int angle;
}
```